# Does Wamp Server differ from a normal internet hosting provider?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, wampserver

I am using wamp server to develop a website using php, mysql, PDO, html and css.

My wamp server is using PHP 5.3.5, MySQL 5.5.8 and Apache 2.2.17, I am also using InnoDB for transactions.

Considering that my internet hosting provider has at least these versions of php, mysql, apache, and supports InnoDB will the website I build act in the exact same way.

Is it possible to design a website in wamp and then expect several errors when going live? And if so how is this overcome?

Thanks.

Comment: It's usually overcome by uploading your site and testing, testing, testing. Typically, testing for consistency, accuracy and "too dumb to happen" errors is the most important part of the process.

Comment: And I would say differences in file systems and configurations are most important if you've verified your host is setup with the same prereqs as you've been working with in your development.

Comment: I agree, but YMMV - I found it's remarkable how interchangeable the filesystems appear from within LAMP - most importantly PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As others note, there are many potential hiccups (but I view them as learning opportunities.) But I've done it this way for over five years and have yet to find a difference that wasn't easily overcome. Just stick to the middle of the road, use defaults as much as makes sense, and have fun. It's a great way to explore the platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can go wrong, most of them having to do with how the web server and PHP are built and configured.

The simplest example is PHP's [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php): there are many things that safe mode does not allow, and turning it off may not be an option if you are on a shared host. Another example is which extensions are enabled in PHP (your app may require one which the host does not have).

Of course this is all moot if you rent the whole server (or a VM), as in this case you will be able to do whatever you please.

For completeness, I have to mention that there might be platform-specific differences in behavior resulting from the same library (which PHP uses to provide some functionality) compiling into different behavior on different platforms (think platform sniffing in C with `#ifdef`). I have been bitten by this in the past, but the possibility is not large enough to worry about it beforehand.

Comment: Yes, it is nice to have a VS/M, although that can also be a curse.

Comment: Probably a newbie question but what a vs/m hosting service compared to a normal service?

Comment: @Basic: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service

Comment: It's something you can probably start without knowing about, though. If you start with simple stuff and the defaults everything should be fine and you can learn as you go.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the issues can be worked around by moving constants into config files, like Jon says.  Some issues will be less in your control and harder to diagnose.  For instance, the [output buffer control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) may be configured differently outside the DocumentRoot you have access to.  This can cause confusing problems when you try to write headers out when other content has already been sent out.  Similar issues with the timeout numbers, etc.

Comment: It is currently set to on, meaning I can place redirects anywhere on the page which is what I need, is this a bad idea? Although I suppose if I pay enough money I can have any settings that I like?